# How to calculate finish time of a process? - Shortest Remaining Time First Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, operating-system

I was coding to calculate the average waiting and turnaround times of processes using the Shortest Remaining Time First Algorithm (SRTF).

I want to print the result in a table like format as shown below.

```
Enter the number of processess:4

Enter the process name, CPU Burst Time, Arrival Time row wise:
1 3 0
2 6 1
3 4 4
4 2 6

    Process CPU     AT      Finish  TT      WT
    1       3       0       3       3       0
    2       6       1       15      14      9
    3       4       4       5       1       1
    4       2       6       5       -1      3

The average turnaround time is: 4.000000
The average waiting time is: 3.000000
```

Here AT = Arrival Time, TT = Turnaround time, WT = Waiting time. But some error appears as the finish times of the processes 3 and 4 are not possible. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int **a;
int return_min(int upto, int n)
{
        int min=1000, idx =-1;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
                if(a[i][1]!=-1 && a[i][2]<=upto && min>a[i][1])
                {
                        min=a[i][1];
                        idx = i;
                }
        }
        return idx;
}


void main()
{
        int n,i,j,time=0, idx,total_tt=0, total_wt=0;
        float  avg_tt, avg_wt;


        printf("Enter the number of processess:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        a=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*n);


        printf("\nEnter the process name, CPU Burst Time, Arrival Time row wise:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                *(a+i)=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*7);
                for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                {

                        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
                }
                a[i][6]=a[i][1];
        }

        while((idx=return_min(time,n)) != -1)
        {
                a[idx][1]--;
                if(a[idx][1] == 0)
                        a[idx][1]--;
                time++;
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
                        if(a[i][1]!=-1 && i!=idx && a[i][2]<=time)
                                a[i][5]++;
                }
        }

        printf("\n\tProcess\tCPU\tAT\tFinish\tTT\tWT\n");

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

                a[i][1]=a[i][6];
                a[i][3]=a[i][5]+a[i][1];
                a[i][4]=a[i][3]-a[i][2];

                for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                {
                        printf("\t%d",a[i][j]);
                }

                printf("\n");
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                total_tt+=a[i][4];

        avg_tt = total_tt/n;
        printf("\nThe average turnaround time is: %f", avg_tt);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                total_wt+=a[i][5];

        avg_wt = total_wt/n;
        printf("\nThe average waiting time is: %f\n", avg_wt);


}
```

What all mistakes am I doing?  Please correct me.

Comment: You should use int main(void){return 0) instead of void(main) and there is no need to cast malloc because its return type is void* and if you do not know, ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode (int i= 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Note:

`Turnaround Time = Finish Time- Arrival Time`

`Waiting Time = Turnaround Time - CPU Burst Time`

Therefore,

You should change your code in the second for loop in the main function as:

```
a[i][4]=a[i][5]+a[i][1];
a[i][3]=a[i][4]+a[i][2];
```

And eventually it'll work correctly.